# HERE.com Places API, "ApiKey is missing" error message, but it isn't

Tags: here-api

I've tried the below request (with two different proper API keys), on the [HERE Places API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/dev_guide/topics/quick-start-find-text-string.html), but I get an auth error.

Request:

```
https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/autosuggest
?at=40.74917,-73.98529
&q=chrysler
&apiKey=g51V9*****N4-_GTA
```

Response:

```
401
{
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "error_description": "ApiKey is missing."
}
```

I've also tried OAuth, I can get the request token, but when I use this for the places request I get an HTML webpage (for HERE place API) as the response, rather than an expected JSON or XML reponse.

Is anyone able to get *any* of the example requests to work for Places API?

Comment: The sole tag you used on this question has a usage guidance starting with a big, fat "DO NOT USE". Please, [edit] the question with what you actually mean and what this question is about.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you pass the parameter apikey as apiKey. I tried your request and it is working as expected please check your request again.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue before aswell. Trying the exact same request as you, in Postman with my own apiKey, made the request successfull.

Try making the URL a single line, there might be newline characters hidden somewhere.

This has solved this issue for me many times using this API.

Example:

```
https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/autosuggest?at=40.74917,-73.98529&q=chrysler&apiKey=g51V9*****N4-_GTA
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the key name it may wrong
you should check it out into the documentation of api. and see key name

try key name apikey or api_key or api-key instead of apiKey

```
https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/autosuggest
?at=40.74917,-73.98529
&q=chrysler
&apikey=g51V9*****N4-_GTA
```

Comment: I've tried all of those, and got the same response. Have you tried something and received a successful response?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/authentication/dev_guide/topics/hosts-mapping.html) for the updated list of domains to use with apiKey.

For places, the domain is: `places.ls.hereapi.com`

<sub>Disclosure: I'm a product manager at HERE Technologies</sub>

Comment: Please note that *explicit* disclosure is required when posting links to sites or products you are affiliated with.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using : https://github.com/julianshen/gin-limiter with the provided example